# Canvas with a image to jpeg

Tags: image, canvas, jpeg

I want to get a .jpg on a canvas, add a rectangle and a String, which is working very good. After that I want to create a jpg out of the canvas, which works fine but the jpg of the canvas does only show the rectangle and the String. Quick Code-example - i know its a ugly canvas - just testing ;)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="meinCanvas" width="600" height="600" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var canv = document.getElementById("meinCanvas");
var context = canv.getContext("2d");
context.fillStyle = "#000000";
context.fillRect(10,10, 200, 100);
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
context.drawImage(img, 300, 300);
};
img.src="one.jpg";
context.font = "bold 12px sans-serif";
context.fillText("test", 500, 500);
imgsr = canv.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
document.write('<img src="' +imgsr +'"/>');
</script>
</html>
}
```

In the upper part (the canvas) the img is shown properly, but in the .jpeg beneth it the img is not shown. Help would be great. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image is not loaded yet when you save it.

Put the toDataUrl in img.onload or link it to an event or timer